# Why is stod() shortening the number I am converting from string to double?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a string to a double, however when i use stod() the double has lost some of it's decimal places.
Here is the relevant code :

```
    cout << line3 << endl;
    float temp = stod(line3);
    cout << temp << endl;
```

For example, when line3 is "4.225308642", temp outputs as 4.22531. What is causing the shortening of the number and how can I fix it?

Comment: A `float` can only store only a fixed, small-ish number of (binary) digits. A small error is expected to happen in most cases when you use floating point variables. A `double` can store more digits, but even that can cause some approximation to happen.

Comment: You will probably run into this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to consider here.

First, formating on a IOStream by default has a precision of 6 significant digits. That explains your result. You can increase the precision with the manipulator `setprecision`.

Then, `float` by itself has a limited precision of about 6 decimal digits as well. Although you can display more, they will be the result of displaying a binary float as decimal, not really an increase of the precision. You can get about 15 decimal digits of precision by using double.

So combining the two, the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::string line3 = "4.225308642";
    std::cout << line3 << '\n';
    float tempf = stof(line3);
    double tempd = stod(line3);
    std::cout << "default: float=" << tempf << ", double=" << tempd << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
    std::cout << "precision(20): float=" << tempf << ", double=" << tempd << '\n';
}
```

has for result:

```
4.225308642
default: float=4.22531, double=4.22531
precision(20): float=4.2253084182739257812, double=4.2253086419999998924
```

Note again that the last digits result of displaying a binary format. There is a precision after which you can't expect a decimal representation matching the input, and 20 is greater than that. That aspect is explained in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).